# How to determine the existance of a "real" keyboard in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, keyboard

I'm building a web page which needs a lot of text input, far more than is convenient on a phone or tablet.

How can I tell if the browser has a real keyboard, so that the page can display a "sorry, please use a device with a keyboard" apology for phones and tablets?

(It's not just the slowness of on-screen keyboards, it's that they also use up 1/3 of the already small screen.)

Comment: While I think the question is valid, I would still mention that it might be better for the users to be able to use the web page with a cell phone, even if it's inconvenient, instead of just locking them out. Many users do not have a device with a real keyboard any more.

Comment: I agree with your opinion. However even Stack Overflow has such a blocking feature. For example, tablet users cannot use the snippet feature. A message box appears when a snippet icon is tapped. I think the OP's question is reasonable.

Comment: @PMF Thanks for your comment, but this includes an augmented text editor which requires significant space for potential completions (10-20 lines).  I do not want to spend significant time and effort trying to make a barely acceptable experience for mobile users, when it is still an unvalidated idea.

Comment: What if they have a tablet and a real keyboard connected to it - how will you decide - this tablet is ok or not?

Comment: @MrR Thanks for the question.  The tablet is OK if, and only, if the on-screen keyboard is not displayed, yet they can press keys.  So perhaps the title of this question should read "How to determine that the on-screen keyboard will not pop-up, yet the user has a method of causing keypresses".